# Exporting SQL Server results with multiple tables to Excel

Tags: sql-server-2008, export-to-excel

I have a database with 69 tables.

Please help me export this

```
exec sp_MSforeachtable 'select top 3 * from ?'
```

The line fetches the top 3 records of each table and prints them in the "Results" tab (as per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11741212/select-the-first-3-rows-of-each-table-in-a-database)).

I would like to export the results into a .xls file.

I tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3306628/exporting-data-from-sql-server-to-excel) which uses sp_makewebtask but I understand this has now been depreciated.

Could you please help?

Many thanks,

Phil

P.S. Database runs on MSSQL 2008

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you might need to add an `ORDER BY` to your query: without it, you will get three random rows from each table, which may or may not be what you want.

Next, is this a one-time task or something you will do regularly? If it's a one-time task then generate a query script dynamically, run it manually and copy and paste the results yourself. This might give you an idea about how to generate the script:

```
select 'select top 3 * from ' + quotename(name) + ' order by SomeColumn union all '
from sys.tables
where... -- add something here if necessary
```

If you need to do this regularly, I would avoid TSQL because it's a very poor language for working with files outside the database. Instead, it's often easier to write a small script to connect to the database, get the data and write the output file. You can use whatever scripting or programming language is most convenient for you and then schedule it with SQL Agent (if that's available in your edition of SQL Server).

Comment: Hi Pondlife, thank you for the reply. Yes, random is fine. It is a one-time task. The script from my post just does the job but the problem is that I don't know how to export the results into an Excel file. In one sentence: I need 1) a random selection of 3 records from each of the 69 tables and 2) saved into an Excel file. 1) was already achieved, I can't do 2), though. Thanks

Comment: If it's a one-time task then as I mentioned you can just copy and paste the results manually from SSMS into Excel. If all 69 tables have the same structure, then the query I suggested will allow you to get all the rows in one result set, so you only have to copy and paste once, not 69 times.